# Mock Stub and Moq Setup act differently ? What is the equivalent of Stub in Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, rhino-mocks

I realized while writing unit testing in two different projects that the behavior of setup in Moq is different than Stub in Rhino-Mocks.

One class uses Mock which has one of these scenarios where I stub

```
for (int i=0; i<ObjectAList.Count; i++)
{
     _translator.Stub(x => x.TranslateToObjectB(ObjectAList[i])).Return(ObjectBList[i]);
}
```

the above example works like a charm.

But when I tried to do the same thing in a different project that uses Moq, using setup, it failed.

```
for (int i=0; i<ObjectAList.Count; i++)
{
     _translator.SetUp(x => x.TranslateToObjectB(ObjectAList[i])).Returns(ObjectBList[i]);
}
```

Instead I had to do something like this,

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var ObjectA in ObjectAList)
{
     _translator.Setup(x => x.ConvertToProcessingFilter(ObjectA)).Returns(ObjectBList[i]);
     i++;
}
```

I am just looking for a reason why stub vs setup behaved so differently. If this is the expected from setup, then what is the equivalent of stub in Moq ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see, is related to [Closures behaving differently in `for` and `foreach` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365350/closures-behaving-differently-in-for-and-foreach-loops).

With:

```
for (int i=0; i<ObjectAList.Count; i++)
{
     _translator.Setup(x => x.TranslateToObjectB(ObjectAList[i])).Returns(ObjectBList[i]);
}
```

you are **closing over (capturing)** the `for` iteration variable. The behavior will depend on *when* the mocking framework evaluates the lambda expression.

Try:

```
for (int i=0; i<ObjectAList.Count; i++)
{
     var j = i;
     _translator.Setup(x => x.TranslateToObjectB(ObjectAList[j])).Returns(ObjectBList[j]);
}
```

instead. Will it work?

You might also be able to do just one setup, similar to this:

```
_translator.Setup(x => x.TranslateToObjectB(It.IsAny<ObjAType>()))
  .Returns((ObjAType a) => ObjectBList[ObjectAList.IndexOf(a)]);
```