# Why does @for loop does not work in Razor and Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

This code works:

```
@page "/"
<button @onclick="@(()=>fun(0))" style="color: @style1[0]">
    Click me
</button>
<button @onclick="@(()=>fun(1))" style="color: @style1[1]">
    Click me
</button>
<button @onclick="@(()=>fun(2))" style="color: @style1[2]">
    Click me
</button>

@code{
    List<string> style1 = new List<string> { "black" , "black", "black" };
    void fun(int m)
    {
       try
       {
           if (style1[m] == "black") style1[m] = "red";
               else style1[m] = "black";
       }
       catch
       {
            Console.WriteLine("m = {0}", m);
       }
    }
}
```

But this one does not:

```
@page "/"
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    <button @onclick="@(()=>fun(i))" style="color: @style1[i]">
        Click me
    </button>
}
@code{
//same as above
}
```

and this is the error in Console (without try-catch):

Unhandled exception rendering component: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

after try-catch:

m = 3

Thanks

Comment: Try adding  temporary variable inside the `for` loop and use it in `fun()`: `var tmp = i;` and `()=>fun(tmp)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Could you please describe what is the difference between these statements and why did it not work?

Comment: This is how [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365350/closures-behaving-differently-in-for-and-foreach-loops) work in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following code (a simpler version of your code in my index.razor)

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" @onclick="(() => ButtonClick(i))">@($"Button {i}") </button>
}
<h4>Value = @value</h4>

@code {

    int value = -1;

    void ButtonClick(int x)
        => value = x;
}
```

Your expectation is that Value will display 1 when you click on Button 1.  Not so, it always displays 3, the final value of `i`.  The button click event submits the value of `i` when the button is clicked, the loop has long completed.

In your code `i` is 3 - the last version of `i` that stopped the for loop. - and m in  `style1[m]` is 3 pointing to a none existent 4th member of `style1`. `Index was out of range` is quite correct, but quite as informative as it could be.

Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees!!